# How to make response.success() wait?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

In the following Cloud function I need to know where and how to put the response.success() so that it gets executed once all the work is done and not before.
I have already checked that the function is doing its job as expected. The only issue is the one I mentioned.
I am trying to use Promises, but what I have done so far did not work.

```
 Parse.Cloud.define
 ("deleteUnitAndDependencies", function(request, response) {
    var unitListQuery;
    unitListQuery = new Parse.Query("UnitList");
    unitListQuery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.unitID);
    unitListQuery.equalTo("ownerID", request.params.userID);
    unitListQuery.find().then(function(resUnit) {
    var sentenceListQuery,sentenceListStatus;
    sentenceListQuery = new Parse.Query("SentenceList");
    sentenceListQuery.equalTo("unit", resUnit[0]);
    sentenceListStatus = sentenceListQuery.find();
    resUnit[0].destroy({});
    return sentenceListStatus;
    }).then(function(resSentence) {
    var translatListQuery,translatListQStatus;
    translatListQuery = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");
    for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
        if (iS == 0 ) {
            translatListQuery.equalTo("sentence", resSentence[iS]);
            continue;
        }
        translatListQuery = Parse.Query.or(translatListQuery,
                                           (new Parse.Query("TranslatList")).equalTo
                                           ("sentence", resSentence[iS]));
    }
    translatListQStatus = translatListQuery.find();
    for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
        resSentence[iS].destroy({});
    }
    return translatListQStatus;
    }).then(function(resTranslat) {
    for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
        resTranslat[iT].destroy({});
    }
    });
   });
```

Comment: you need to change `doSomeBigWork` to accept a callback which will gte called once the async work is completed... then call `response.success();` in the callback

Comment: Yes thanks, I guess that is a way to do it. Since I am (beginning) into Promises at the moment I was hoping there would be a cleaner way using a Promise rather than a callback.

Comment: Of course you can use a promise... the method `doSomeBigWork` need to return a promise in whose success callback you can call `response.success();`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1kyvL0Lh/1/

Comment: @Michel: A promise is just another way to pass a callback. Consider it an alternative syntax for callbacks. Instead of `f(arg,callback)` you do `f(arg).then(callback)`. It doesn't change the need for a callback. Just provides a nicer syntax for when you need to nest lots of callbacks.

Comment: @slebetman: After reading on the net about it, I understand that. Nevertheless I still find it rather tricky to use and apply. I have tried a few ways to make my code work (see the text of my question), but I still can't put the `response.success();` in the right place.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: I did try, a few ways to apply what is in your link, but it did not work. I must have made some mistakes. So I edited the question to be closer to the real case I am facing, making the code a bit longer to read.

Comment: can you tell me where is the problem in the code..

Comment: @Arun P Johny: The problem is that I don't know how to place  `response.success();`.The way it is, it works fine on the server, but having no `response.success();` something is missing for the app to react as it should.
On the other hand if I add a line `response.success();`, the app side is fine, but the job on the server side isn’t done anymore. I suppose it is because `response.success();` is executed too fast and does not wait for the rest of the job to be done on the server.

Comment: On editing, `response.success()` has disappeared from the code so it's hard to know what's being asked.

Comment: @ Roamer-1888 : `response.success();` is not in the code from start. This is how I make it work on the server. Where and how should I put  `response.success();` in the code (while keeping what is now working) is exactly my question.

Comment: Why not just chain `.then(response.success)`?

Comment: @ Roamer-1888 : That sounds interesting! And at which point should I do that?
Excuse my naive question, but I only started to tackle Promises yesterday so I am from being an expert :)

Comment: Right at the end of the chain - bottom of the outermost function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73631/discussion-between-michel-and-roamer-1888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into similar issues, I put here the solution I came up with. It is working the way I want, as far as I have checked at this point.
If some promise-expert reads this and has comments and suggestions to make it better please let us know.

```
Parse.Cloud.define
("deleteUnitAndDependencies", function(request, response) {
 var unitListQuery;
 unitListQuery = new Parse.Query("UnitList");
 unitListQuery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.unitID);
 unitListQuery.equalTo("ownerID", request.params.userID);

 unitListQuery.find().then
 (function(resUnit) {
  // If there is no UNIT we return an error.
  if (!resUnit.length) response.error("NO-UNIT");

  var sentenceListQuery;
  sentenceListQuery = new Parse.Query("SentenceList");
  sentenceListQuery.equalTo("unit", resUnit[0]);

  sentenceListQuery.find().then
  (function(resSentence) {
   var translatListQuery,tmpQuery;
   translatListQuery = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");

   for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
    if (iS == 0 ) {
        translatListQuery.equalTo("sentence", resSentence[iS]);
        continue;
    }

    tmpQuery = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");
    tmpQuery.equalTo("sentence", resSentence[iS]);
    translatListQuery = Parse.Query.or(translatListQuery,tmpQuery);
   }

   translatListQuery.find().then
   (function(resTranslat) {
    var destroyPromises = [];
    for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
        destroyPromises.push(resTranslat[iT].destroy({}));
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
    }).then
   (function() {
    var destroyPromises = [];
    for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
        destroyPromises.push(resSentence[iS].destroy({}));
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
    }).then
   (function() {
    return resUnit[0].destroy({});
    }).then(response.success);
   });
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a function into `doSomeBigWork`, when it's done with its async stuff, have it then call that function.

```
doSomeBigWork(function() {
    response.success();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple parts in your code that return promises. You need to include these in your promise chain. This is as simple as using a return statement.

This block for example:

```
    translatListQStatus = translatListQuery.find();
    for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
        resSentence[iS].destroy({});
    }
    return translatListQStatus;
}).then(function(resTranslat) {
    for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
        resTranslat[iT].destroy({});
    }
});
```

You want to wait for those `destroy` calls to finish. Look at this section of the help on [Promise Chaining in Parallel](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel)

```
    var findResults;
    translatListQStatus = translatListQuery.find()
    .then(function(resTranslat) {
        var destroyPromises = [];
        for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
            destroyPromises.push(resSentence[iS].destroy({}));
        }

        // save these so we can return them at the end
        findResults = resTranslat;

        // return a promise here
        return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
    })
    .then(function() {
        // return the results we saved
        return findResults;
    });

    return translatListQStatus;
}).then(function(resTranslat) {
    var destroyPromises = [];
    for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
        destroyPromises.push(resTranslat[iT].destroy({}));
    }

    return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
});
```

Comment: I am looking at your answer and the link you mention on Parse. I think I need to reverse partly the order of my code. When I explore the tree structure (top=Unit, next level:Sentences, next level:Translations) I need to go top->down, but when I destroy it I need to go bottom->up.

Comment: Looking at the code you write, it seems you are destroying Sentences before you destroy Translations.
But that cannot be, because once a Sentence is destroyed there is no more access to its Translations in order to destroy them.
(Unless I am missing one point, or you just followed the order of my own writing —which was meant to solve this particular issue by using an intermediate status variable, but I am not sure it would fully work any way-).

Comment: I found a solution, please take a look if you have time. And let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: Each of your calls to `find()` return promises, so you should return those so that they become part of the promise chain. The code after `find()` will need to be put in the next `then()` block.

Comment: If you are referring to the indentations I have at some point, then I agree and I wanted to do as you say. But I didn't know the way to keep the scope of variables from one .then block to the next, this is why I put some .then blocks nested in another. When I delete the list of translations (resTranslat) I need to keep an access to the list of sentences (resSentence), in order to delete them later.

Comment: I create a scope variable before my first promise `var scope = {};` then anytime I need to save something that all parts of the promise can see I just set it `scope.resUnit = resUnit;`, that way if I need to access it in a later promise I just read `scope.resUnit`

Comment: I see. In other words you use some kind of global variable?

Answer (score 1):

Michel, congratulations at getting it to work. That's no small achievement for someone who has been using promises for just a couple of days.

You will find that by creating a `destroy()` utility, you can avoid code repetition and compact the main routine right down.

With that utility and further simplifications/rearrangements, I ended up with this :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUnitAndDependencies", function(request, response) {
    //A utility function that gets called twice
    function destroy(arr) {
        return Parse.Promise.when(arr.map(function(r) {
            return r.destroy({});
        }));
    }
    var unitListQuery = new Parse.Query("UnitList");
    unitListQuery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.unitID);
    unitListQuery.equalTo("ownerID", request.params.userID);
    unitListQuery.find().then(function(resUnit) {
        var sentenceListQuery = new Parse.Query("SentenceList");
        sentenceListQuery.equalTo("unit", resUnit[0]);
        return sentenceListQuery.find().then(function(resSentence) {
            var translatListQuery = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");
            translatListQuery.equalTo("sentence", resSentence[0]);
            for (var iS = 1; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {//loop counter now starts at 1
                translatListQuery = Parse.Query.or(translatListQuery, (new Parse.Query("TranslatList")).equalTo("sentence", resSentence[iS]));
            }
            return translatListQuery.find().then(destroy).then(function() {
                return destroy(resSentence.concat(resUnit[0]));
            });
        });
    }).then(response.success);
});
```

*untested*

**Edit**

As the destroys seem not to need to wait for each other, you should be able to do the `.concat()` trick twice, and call `destroy()` once.

```
return translatListQuery.find().then(function(resTranslat) {
    return destroy(resTranslat.concat(resSentence).concat(resUnit[0]));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your way is shorter. I need to look into it closely.

Comment: Michael, yes I employ several tricks to make the code concise. One of them is to purge lots of white-space :-)